# Query posts by views on category page

Tags: categories, wp-query, popular-posts

I'm having trouble trying to create a second query on the category.php pages, what I'm trying to achieve is displaying the most popular posts from the current category archive page being viewed.

This is what I have so far.

```
<?php // The Query
    global $wp_query;

    $term = $wp_query->queried_object;

    $args=array(
        'meta_key' => 'views',
        'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'posts_per_page' => 5,
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy'  => $term->taxonomy,
                    'field'     => 'slug',
                    'terms'     => $term->slug,
                    )
                )
        );

    $new_query = null;
    $new_query = new WP_Query($args);

    while ($new_query->have_posts()) : $new_query->the_post(); ?>

    <?php include(TEMPLATEPATH.'/category-slider.php'); ?>

<?php
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Now for the most part it works but the only problem I'm having is that posts_per_page is only returning one post no matter what number I set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't nullify the main query, this breaks stuff. Also, avoid using the `$wp_query` global as a custom variable. This breaks the main query and causes issues. You can also try adding `'suppress_filters' => true,` to your arguments to suppress any custom filters if you are using any custom filters.

Also, don't use `TEMPLATEPATH`, it is due to be depreciated according to a recent track ticket. Use `get_template_part()` instead

Try the following

```
<?php // The Query
    global $wp_query;

    $term = $wp_query->queried_object;

    $args=array(
        'meta_key' => 'views',
        'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'posts_per_page' => 5,
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'suppress_filters' => true,
        'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy'  => $term->taxonomy,
                    'field'     => 'slug',
                    'terms'     => $term->slug,
                    )
                )
        );

    $new_query = new WP_Query($args);

    while ($new_query->have_posts()) : $new_query->the_post(); ?>

    <?php get_template_part( category-slider ); ?>

<?php
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Apart from this, everything should work, except if you are using `query_posts` somewhere on the page which will break everything

Comment: get_template_directory_uri broke the page.

Comment: Switched it to get_template_part and that worked but it's still only returning one item.

Comment: Oh crap, sorry about that, typo, posted the answer before leaving for work :-). What happens if you remove the tax query, do you get more posts back

Comment: Tried it, still no luck.

Comment: Ok, then your problem is with your meta key. Are these correct. Do you get the correct amount of posts if you remove the meta key and ordering. It is really strange that it is not working. If nothing works, I will test it all a bit later. Still at work

Comment: Your code works on my side. There is something else that is failing your code

Comment: Not sure, I removed 'meta_key' => 'views', 'orderby' => 'meta_value_num' and still it's only returning one item, query_posts is no where in the category template.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is that something inside `category-slider.php` is breaking something, or stopping your loop. As I said, I've tested your code, and it works. Replace `get_template_part( category-slider );` with `the_title()` and retest. Turn on debugging as well.

Comment: You were right, it's actually has something to do with the slider itself not returning a list once I added the_title(), it worked.

Comment: Glad you solved it. This question haunted me. Enjoy :-)